# Android unrecognized by Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, mtp

I recently migrated from Linux Mint 18 to **Debian 8.7.1 (Jessie)**, with **Xfce** as desktop manager and **Thunar** as file explorer.

To my dismay, while Mint recognized my **Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini (CM13 stable)** while in **MTP** mode, Debian blatantly ignored the device.

My question is simple: I was able to interact with my phone by means of **adb**, but this is a rather cumbersome way of moving files around. Is there a way to make Debian (and Thunar) recognize my phone, while using the MTP protocol?

The only installation disc I used when installing Debian was the **DVD 1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's the relevant Debian page on MTP.](https://wiki.debian.org/mtp)
For Xfce:
 # apt-get install gvfs-backends
 # reboot